# ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position

Tags: python, hex

I have a hexadecimal string

```
hexDecoded = '0xa506f7374696e6720446174653a204a756c792031322c2032303038205b45426f6f6b20233238395d0a52656c6561736520446174653a204a756c792c20313939350a5b4c61737420757064617465643a204a616e756172792031332c20323031325d0a0a0a4c616e67756167653a20456e676c6973680a0a0a2a2a2a205354'
```

On trying to obtain text as

```
text = bytearray.fromhex(hexDecoded.lstrip('0x')).decode()
```

I get the error

**ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 255**

I can't understand why the code is looking at postion 255 in the hexadecimal string when the length of stripped hexadecimal string is only 255.

Any ideas what is missing here.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because that string contains an odd number of digits, leaving the trailing `4` as a singleton.

`bytearray.fromhex('4')` produces the same error.

If you change it to `04`, it works.